# Use API key between angularJS and Laravel

Tags: angularjs, laravel, restful-authentication, jwt, api-key

I'm building an API based application, which uses Laravel as the backend and AngularJS for the front-end.

User Authentication between the front-end and the API is relatively straightforward, using JSON web-tokens (JWT). [This tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/token-based-authentication-for-angularjs-and-laravel-apps) was especially helpful

But much of my front end app is not user-authenticated, it simply needs to be protected by an API key.

I would like to continue using the JWT approach if possible, but i can't find a single package or guide for securing a front-end application with a simple API key (with no initial user login). I don't want to re-invent the wheel, there must be existing solutions for this common problem..

Does anyone have any experience securing and API based AngularJS frount end for use with a custom API? Are there any packages which exist to do this?

NOTE: I have investigated Auth0, which is great, but it is has several problems (the cost, no free support for a custom user DB, no built-in support for a simple API-key)

Thanks

Comment: I can't believe this is not a common problem! Surely every API based site must include an API key and a user auth system? What am i missing here...

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can think of to handle this is to create a new Laravel user for your angular site.

You will also need a proxy script which contains the site's user credentials.  It would reach out to Laravel with
those credentials and return the JWT.  Then you just call this proxy script from Angular to get your token.  The purpose
of the proxy script being a good way to hide those credentials from users.

This way, you don't need to change anything in your API as it's really just a new user accessing the site.  If or when 
the user needs to elevate his credentials by signing in as himself, you can also continue to use the proxy script and
have it replace those default site credentials with the user credentials before grabbing the JWT from Laravel.

Comment: thanks! What happens when the user wants to log in as themselves? They would need to be automatically logged out of the fake user and logged in again  i suppose... seems complicated :/

Comment: You wouldn't need to log anyone out.  You just send the user's own credentials instead of the site's credentials through the proxy script and it returns a new JWT to Angular.  As far as your API is concerned, there are no logins or sessions.  It just receives and grants privileges based on the token it receives.